# Alternatives to inotify to detect when a new file is created under a folder

Tags: c++, linux, inotify

I am developing my program on Linux, is there a programmatic way to detect when another application creates/copies a file under/to a specific folder. I want to detect the new file as fast as it is created and I would like to process the file.

As far as I researched I can accomplish this using inotify. Are there any better alternatives?

Comment: You seem to already know the answer, which is indeed to use inotify.

Comment: What's wrong with inotify? It's great. And it fits into your existing epoll multiplexer loop (which I hope you have).

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it, I just wanted to see what other options I have, before getting my hands dirty with it.

Comment: is inotify scalable? IS there not a limit on the number of watches?

Answer (score 1):

inotify is the proper API provided by the Linux kernel. Your toolkit may have convenience on top of it, e.g. `KDirWatch` from libkdecore, but that uses inotify internally.

Using API from a toolkit is a good idea when your program is cross-platform.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.highscore.de/boost/dir_monitor.zip on http://en.highscore.de/cpp/boost/asio.html is a cross-platform C++ Boost solution, though I haven't tried it yet.

http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/ASIO-file-monitoring-help-td4645105.html has code using it that is wrong, the fix looks to be to make a few more objects the author assumed could be temporary permanent instead.

Answer (score 1):

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fanotify.7.html is another option

This is a nice article which sums all methods http://www.lanedo.com/filesystem-monitoring-linux-kernel/